# How can i force the user to change password every six month in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, change-password

I'm using Angular and node.js
I have many users in my app and each user has a password.
How can i force the user to change password every six month?
Is there a library that doing this?

Comment: You could check each day which passwords weren't updated since six months and mark them on your DB, so if the user wants to login again, he gets a message / redirection to change his password.

Answer (score 0):

you should do it on backend to force user and need to store last user password change time and check it if it’s six months far from that

Comment: Thanks,
I thought about it
But there is no library that handles this automatically?

Comment: I don’t know any but it’s simple to code but must time there is a simpler hack specifically for your app architecture to implement.